# How can i do this in C#?

Tags: c#

I want to do something like this:

```
Button button = new Button("Button");
button.addClickListener(new ClickListener(){
//Implement required methods here..
});
```

How can i do this in C#?

Comment: (I want to implement my own little gui for my project in this language)

Comment: I would recommend you take a look at a _C# Windows Forms_ tutorial to get you started.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attach the event handler:

```
button.Click += myClickEvent;
...
protected void myClickEvent(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     // do your thing
}
```